# What legal questions must be answered to determine the international copyright status of generated art?

Tags: copyright, international, fair-use

Below is my best understanding of how art is generated by machine learning. I understand that the copyright ownership of the final product and any infringement in the process is currently an open question.

Are any of the steps below:

- already obviously fair use
- identified as the core of the legal problem (e.g. "we don't know if step X is transformative")

I am asking in the context of international law.

[image]

Comment: One problem with the question is that "fair use" is a term of art in US law, as is the consideration of transformativity.

Comment: @user6726 I didn't realize that, my point of reference is the EFF so I guess that explains it; I'll do some reading and internationalize my question (edits welcome)

Answer (score 1):

### Authorship

Copyright can only be granted to a human author. The end user might have a copyright in the prompt, but as it is currently held, nobody can hold a copyright in the resulting images, as they have no human author.

Comment: so this could be a system for generating public domain work? fascinating! (and too good to be true, I'm sure :D)

Comment: @lofidevops no it is not: if you prompt the AI to "draw iron man" it infringes on iron-man.